# loading takes so much time sometimes in android asynctask

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using AsyncTask to call the web service and render the data I got from web service.

this is working fine but sometimes Progress Dialog doesn't get dismissed and not able to see the reason for this in log also.

Example:: 
I have a web service which is getting called to get the list view data with indexing(for 1 it will return first 5 data and for 2 it will return second 5 data and so on)

once I click page 1 button it returns data and render the same and when I click the page 2 button it starts loading and doesn't dismiss. neither the data is rendered nor the progress dialog is dismissed.
now i closed the app and relaunched again and this time both the situation worked very well.

Any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Code for Asynctask :

```
public class getList extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String text = null;
        JSONObject json; 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //Configuration.empcode.trim()
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(ListURL+UserCode+"/"+indexNo);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                // String result = EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity)
                // response);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                text = sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   



        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(result!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);   
                JSONArray resultArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("Table");

                for(int i =0;i<resultArray.length();i++)
                {   
                    JSONObject resultObjects = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Code = resultObjects.getString("Code");
                    Title = resultObjects.getString("Title");
                    status= resultObjects.getString("status");
                    date= resultObjects.getString("date");


                    TitleList.add(Title);
                    CodeList.add(Code);
                    statusList.add(status);
                    dateList.add(date);

                    int count = db.getInProgressCount(CourseCode);  

                    if(count==0)
                    {
                        db.addInProgress(new InProgressTable(Code,Title,status,date));
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        db.updateInProgress(new InProgressTable(Code,Title,status,date));
                    }
                }

                adapter = new CustomInProgressList(getActivity(),TitleList,CodeList,statusList,dateList);

                //adapter.setCustomButtonListner(Catalog_Activity.this);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                scrollMyListViewToBottom(resultArray.length());
                int count = db.getAllInProgressCount();
                if (adapter.getCount()<1 && count<1){
                    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    noRes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    noRes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (resultArray.length()<5);
                loadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
            builder.setTitle("Alert");              
            builder.setMessage("Data is not available, Please try again later"); 
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
              { 
               dialog.cancel();
              } 
            }); 

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); 
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used multiple Asynctask in my application.
Is that a Problem??

Comment: show your codes please )

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @StepanMaksymov see my updated post

Comment: @Jack see my updated post

Comment: May bey your service call two time print log in  onPreExecute() whether it print two time.

Comment: when you call second page it will call two time so first progress bar reference was removed and it will not dismiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is your problem -

`pDialog` as I understand is declared in activity. Lets see the situation with 2 requests.

when you started first one, and immediately start another - your `pDialog` is now new dialog (it points to another dialog) and first one exists without point to it, and it's not closed! this is why you have not closed dialog.

this will be caused in situation when:

1) first request started;

2) second request started before first request ended;

you must handle one dialog in all your requests or close dialog before it's reinitialisation.

Comment: I will try that, however the solution seems very logical.thanks